# ¿Donde pego los archivos que descargo del marketplace de Genexus?

Tags: genexus, genexus15

Por ejemplo en la genexus market place hay ejemplo MenuGx entonces se descarga un winrar pero donde pego estas carpetas. alguien que sepa de genexus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los descomprimes bajo el directorio UserControls donde tengas instalado GeneXus y luego ejecutas "genexus.exe /install"

Más información: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?5920,HowTo%3A%20Installing%20User%20Controls#Manual+installation

Comment: perfecto muchas gracias, sabras como installar un dll para que desde genexus pueda crear Excel? tengo entendido que trae una dll llamada EppPlues.dll pero como inicio esto. Probe con un evento y nada.